# Only Ciper is not importing , importerror but not for other modules like Random in Crypto

Tags: python-2.7, import, centos, importerror, pycrypto

I have installed Crypto , using pip install pycrypto.

It got installed perfectly in CentOS. Able to see all module files under Crypto folder. /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto.

in terminal, when importing Crypto. Able to do it.

But getting error for importing Ciper from Crypto with below 
from Crypto.Ciper import AES

Says below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named Ciper

But no import error for other modules in Crypto

> > > from Crypto import Hash
> > >
> > > from Crypto import Signature
> > >
> > > from Crypto import Util
> > >
> > > from Crypto import Ciper

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name Ciper

See for detailed imports in my terminal

Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import os
> > >
> > > import Crypto
> > >
> > > print Crypto.**file**

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/**init**.pyc

> > > print dir(Crypto)

['**all**', '**builtins**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**revision**', '**version**', 'version_info']

> > > print os.listdir(os.path.dirname(Crypto.**file**))

['Protocol', 'Util', 'pct_warnings.py', '**init**.pyc', '**init**.py', 'Signature', 'PublicKey', 'Cipher', 'Hash', 'SelfTest', 'pct_warnings.pyc', 'Random']

Any ideas how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

That module is available as an RPM package from the EPEL repository. Uninstall what you have with pip first, then run `yum install python-crypto`.

Comment: It does not install it with yum install as well. Used the same command as you mentioned.

Comment: yum installing it as successfully, but when i do this "from Crypto.Ciper import AES" throws an error "No module named "

Comment: But it is importing other modules in Crypto, but not for Ciper :(

Comment: You've got a typo, missing an "h" in "Cipher".  Try `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. very shameful on my self... Didnt able to check spelling itself... its my bad...